# Unable to cast string to int32

Tags: c#, string, integer

I have this string:

```
"-1238903096.0"
```

When I try to cast it to an Int32 using Convert.ToInt32() or int.parse / int.TryParse i get an FormatException : *"Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."*

But normally it should work, because that value is not exceeding the Int32.MinValue Range?
Any Ideas :/ ?

Comment: Yeah, your value has a decimal point, so you have to parse it as `double` or `decimal`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution! :)

Comment: slightly off-topic (and pedantic), but using `Convert.ToInt32` is not considered casting, it would be considered parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Your value has a decimal point best to parse it as a decimal or double.

You could also remove the decimal point and then parse it as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Xela is right, the decimal point is messing you up.  Try to convert to a double before you convert it to an integer.

```
int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(s));
```